# How to set a timeout using axios without cancelling API call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Bit of background, I have this API call that can be quite lengthy in its response (talking about over a minute in some instances, but 10-15 seconds for the most part). What I'd like to do is set a timeout on the client side while the backend continues to process the call. I'm using axios to handle http request and I know there is a `timeout` key that is default is `0` meaning that theres no timeout so the call will continue until either succeeds or fails. I tried to set it to `1` to see how this would handle a one millisecond timeout and the call is cancelled...which makes sense. My question now is, how can I implement a timeout on the client side without cancelling the HTTP request?
Some code to get your head around what I've tried.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios"

function App() {
  const fetchLongRequest = async () => {
    try{

// All peachy over here if no timeout is implemented...

      const myRequest = await axios({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
        headers: {
          accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
      })
      console.log("SUCCESS!", JSON.stringify(myRequest.data, null, 2))
    }catch(error){
      console.log("FAIL!", error.message)
    }
  }

  return (
   <button onClick={() => fetchLongRequest()}>Fetch</button>
  );
}

export default App;
```

now this is my introduction of the timeout

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const fetchLongRequest = async () => {

// timeout works as expected but I'd like to let the call go to the backend and do its thing. 

    try {
      const myRequest = await axios({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
        headers: {
          accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        timeout: 1,
      });
      console.log("SUCCESS!", JSON.stringify(myRequest.data, null, 2));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("FAIL!", error.message);
    }
  };

  return <button onClick={() => fetchLongRequest()}>Fetch</button>;
}

export default App;
```

I know the request is a bit odd as it opens many questions such as error handling, how to know when this call is done, etc. I'd like to get some feedback in how I can achieve this task...please :)

Comment: what would you like to happen if/when the time expires? by the way, you know the rest of your code, i.e. code that isn't anything to do with this request, will keep on running, this long request won't "block"

Comment: What id like to do is to just let the user know that this request is taking a bit longer than expected but it’s being professed. And I thought the request would block once it reached the timeout limit, is that not so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you need is a timeout set BEFORE the request

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
    const fetchLongRequest = async () => {
        
        const waitTime = 5000;
        setTimeout(() => console.log("Request taking a long time"), waitTime);
        try {
            const result = await axios({
                url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
                headers: {
                    accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                }
            });
            console.log("SUCCESS!", JSON.stringify(result.data, null, 2));
        } catch(error) {
            console.log("FAIL!", error.message);
        }
    };
    return <button onClick = {() => fetchLongRequest()}>Fetch </button> ;
}
export default App;
```

---

### The original solutions below are total overkill!!

I think this will do what you want, uses Promise.race

> note: this is still not quite right as far as error handling goes

the `handleError` function is purely so if a the request fails before the timeout the failure isn't output twice

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
    const fetchLongRequest = async () => {
        
        const waitTime = 5000;
        const handleError = error => {
            // this makes sure that the FAIL output isn't repeated in the case when there's a failure before the timeout
            if (!error.handled) {
                if (error.timedout) {
                    console.log("TIMEDOUT", error.timedout);
                } else {
                    console.log("FAIL!", error.message);
                    error.handled = true;
                    throw error;
                }
            }
        };
        const makeRequest = async () => {
            try {
                const result = await axios({
                    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
                    headers: {
                        accept: "application/json",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    }
                });
                console.log("SUCCESS!", JSON.stringify(result.data, null, 2));
            } catch(error) {
                return handleError(error);
            }
        };
        const timer = new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(reject, waitTime, {timedout: "request taking a long time"}));
        try {
            await Promise.race([makeRequest(), timer]);
        } catch(error) {
            handleError(error);
        }
    };
    return <button onClick = {() => fetchLongRequest()}>Fetch </button> ;
}
export default App;
```

As a side note, this code is far cleaner without `async`/`await` - though, to be fair, I'm not as fluent using `async`/`await` as I am with Promises alone - I've used Promises since before there was a `.catch` :p

> non `async`/`await` implementation

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
    const fetchLongRequest = () => {
        
        const waitTime = 5000;
        const handleError = error => {
            // this makes sure that the FAIL output isn't repeated in the case when there's a failure before the timeout
            if (!error.handled) {
                if (error.timedout) {
                    console.log("TIMEDOUT", error.timedout);
                } else {
                    console.log("FAIL!", error.message);
                    error.handled = true;
                    throw error;
                }
            }
        };
        
        const myRequest = axios({
            url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
            headers: {
                accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            }
        }).then(result => {
            console.log("SUCCESS!", JSON.stringify(result.data, null, 2));
        }).catch(handleError);
        
        const timer = new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(reject, waitTime, {timedout: "request taking a long time"}));
        
        return Promise.race([myRequest, timer]).catch(handleError);
    };
    return <button onClick = {() => fetchLongRequest()}>Fetch </button> ;
}
export default App;
```

Of course "cleaner" is just my opinion

Comment: Beautiful, I can see it now. I get what you said about before regarding the blocking, when I saw the canceled status on the network tab it got me thinking if the call was just aborted and it wasn’t being processed.

Comment: @Caliman - despite the comment about error handling, after thinking about it, I don't think there's the potential of an unhandled rejection with this code, since the Promise.race rejection is handled, and I presume Promise.race would "handle" any and all rejections internally - I just don't like the idea of an unhandled promise rejection :p

Comment: @Caliman - as an aside, there used to be a Promise-like thing that, in `.then` not only did it have `onResolve`, and `onReject` ... but a third callback, `onProgress` - would've been useful in this case - though, it could never work with `async`/`await`

Comment: If it’s not too much to ask, what’s the cleaner implementation you mention at the end? Would you mind showing an example? If not, you’ve done enough to get me unblocked and I’m forever grateful :). Edit: on another note you’re right! I completely forgot about the those callbacks! And yes, in this case them bad boys would’ve made life much easier.

Comment: Really appreciate your help Jaromanda X! Thanks so much.

Comment: @Caliman - I've been thinking about it ... and think while my code is OK, there may be a better way ... just nutting it out

Comment: Totally overthought the whole thing :p

Comment: No worries mate :D

Comment: @Caliman - the solution is so simple I'm embarrassed by my originals :p once I realised the code is run as an event handler, it dawned on my how simple the solution is

Comment: Bruh...lmao, wow even I just noticed, been banging my head for the good part of an hour on this....really, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Axios API call is `promise-based` so you could simply use `then` and `catch` block to perform some tasks on completion without using `await` then it'll simply run in background without blocking client-side. Using timeout for such scenario is not permissible because on a slow network it may take a minute to complete and once your timeout completed it'll will block client-side. Instead of using `await` which will block your request remove it and it simply run asynchronously which I think you wanna achieve.

```
const myRequest = axios({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
        headers: {
          accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
      })
```

Comment: it already doesn't block the client side ... the request remains asynchronous regardless of `await` - asynchronous code *never blocks*

Comment: You can also try setting timeout to  10000 (as default unit is `ms` and you requirement is minimum of 10seconds which is equivalent to 10000ms)

Comment: but that will cancel the request after 10 seconds - doesn't matter if you put 20000 ... the request can take over a minute, but that isn't considered a failure, OP wants a notification if the request is taking longer than *some time* but wants the request to continue